# Selenium: Iterating through groups of elements

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've done this with BeautifulSoup but it's a bit cumbersome, and I'm trying to figure out if I can do it directly with Selenium.

Let's say I have the following HTML, which repeats multiple times in the page source with identical elements but different contents:

```
<div class="person">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="http://www.url.com/johnsmith/">John Smith</a>
    </div>
    <div class="company">
        <a href="http://www.url.com/company/">SalesForce</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to build a dictionary where the entry for each person looks like:

```
dict = {'name' : 'John Smith', 'company' : 'SalesForce'}
```

I can easily get Selenium to produce a list of the contents of each top level element by doing:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('person')
```

But then I can't iterate through the list because the above method doesn't narrow the scope/source to just the contents of that element.

If I try to do something like this:

```
people = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('person')
for person in people:
    print person.find_element_by_xpath['//div[@class="title"]//a').text
```

I just get the same name over and over again.

I need to do this group by group because in my case, iterating through the whole page and appending each tag individually won't work (there's infinite scrolling, so it would be really inefficient).

Does anyone know whether it's possible to do this directly in Selenium, and if so how?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`find_elements_by_class_name()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name) to get all blocks and [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) to get `title` and `company` for each person:

```
persons = []
for person in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('person'):
    title = person.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/a').text
    company = person.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="company"]/a').text

    persons.append({'title': title, 'company': company})
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense and yet it doesn't work. Please see the updated sample code in my OP, which I believe is the same as what you posted. It returns the same name (I'm guessing from the first object in the list) over and over again. It doesn't seem to be narrowing the scope...

Comment: @AutomaticStatic I've updated the answer in short after posting it. There was an error (used `driver` instead of `person` in the loop). Please check again. Thanks.

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you wrote (except with a print statement to check what it's returning) and it's still returning the same name over and over again.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic ok, I've updated the answer and switched to `find_element_by_xpath()`, please recheck.

Comment: is the .// as opposed to // to indicate that it's a child? Sorry if it's a dumb question. I'm slowly becoming familiar with xpath notation.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic yeah, dot is key here, we are saying the engine to search in the scope of the element.

Comment: @alecxe here is my question. can you please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232248/how-to-put-mulitple-value-in-loop-and-result-to-csv-python-selenium

Comment: When using with WebDriver Wait? The same loop?