# Selenium: For loop breaks find_element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

This one really has me stumped. It's related to this question: [Selenium: Iterating through groups of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006698/selenium-iterating-through-groups-of-elements)

This works fine:

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_1zf"]//div[@class="_946"]//div[contains(text(), "Lives in")]').text
```

This does not:

```
group = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_1zf')
for person in group:
    print person.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="_946"]//div[contains(text(), "Lives in")]').text
```

When I put it in the loop, suddenly the element can't be found.

Comment: This is probably because there are multiple elements with `class="_1zf"` and the first one found doesn't have `.//div[@class="_946"]//div[contains(text(), "Lives in")]` element inside.

Comment: It's there, but there was an intervening element I missed. What's weird is that sometimes it seems to find the child that contains "Lives in" anyway and sometimes it doesn't. I've now made the xpath fully explicit. Back to dealing with infinite scroll. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure it is working at all. `group` refers to list[WebElement], right? and now for each element in list of WebElements you are trying to apply method `find_element_by_xpath`. Am I missing something in this flow?

Comment: Okay, this explains the problem. Thanks. (the weird part is most likely because of the way the page is loaded - asynchronously).

Comment: @olyv For clarification, see alexce's answer in the thread I linked to in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

@AutomaticStatic:

group is the list of elements
person is one of the elements present in the list of elements in group

```
group = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_1zf')
# group is the list of elements

for person in group:
    print person.text
    # person is one of the elements present in the list of elements in group
```

Hope so it will work now for you.