# Selenium WebDriver "find_element_by_xpath" on multiple elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to make a scraper that gets all the values of a list of items sold on a web page. The problem is that I get in return for the whole loop just the first value. I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Page source: https://allegro.pl/listing?string=windows&where=%2Flisting&order=m&bmatch=ss-base-relevance-floki-5-nga-hcp-wp-eng-ele-1-4-0501

```
mains = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_433675f"]')
for main in mains:
    pname = main.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[@class="_342830a c3169ab "]').text
    print pname
```

Comment: Post a link to a sample page on the site you are scraping.

Comment: I am trying to get the details for all the items there are in the page https://allegro.pl/listing?string=windows&order=m&bmatch=ss-base-relevance-floki-5-nga-hcp-wp-ele-1-1-0427

Comment: I got inspiration from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006698/selenium-iterating-through-groups-of-elements I tried to apply it to my scenario and I made a test adapting few lines of my code to this: for main in mains: url = main.find_element_by_xpath('//a').get_attribute('href') pname = main.find_element_by_xpath('.//h2[@class="_342830a c3169ab "]').text However, the result I get is an error. More confused than before...

Comment: Can anybody help me with this? I am still trying to figure it out :(

Comment: Post a [mcve] in order to get better help. As it is, your problem could be anything. One thing that jumps out at me, is that you are using `find_element_by_xpath` and the locator you are supplying depends on `@class`. Have you considered `find_element_by_classname`? But without the page source, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I have updated the question following the guideline. I have also tried to use find_element_by_class_name but it didn't help.