# How can I iterate over anchors assigned to JavaScript functions in Selenium using python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project using Selenium in Python. I have successfully scraped a set of anchors from a website, and I want to iterate over these anchors, click each link, run some code to extract data from the webpage, and then move to the next anchor in the set.

The anchors I'm working with look like this:

```
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1','Page$2')">2</a>
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1','Page$3')">3</a>
```

I have stored these anchors in a variable as follows:

```
    anchors = d.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a')
```

When I attempt to iterate over the anchors and click each link, I encounter a StaleElementReferenceException. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    i = 0
    for a in anchors:
        anchors[i].click()
        *Code to extract data from the webpage*
        i += 1
```

I have tried various versions of this code, including more robust solutions found in other Stack Overflow threads, but the issue persists. The error message I receive is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
```

I have checked that the table containing the anchors and the anchors themselves do not change when navigating between pages. The XPaths for both remain the same.

I have referred to the following Stack Overflow threads without success:

[Fetch all href link using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759787/fetch-all-href-link-using-selenium-in-python)
[Selenium: Iterating through groups of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006698/selenium-iterating-through-groups-of-elements)

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or solutions to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that you want to navigate through the pages of a results list. In this case, proceed in the same way as with human browsing. Take the first page, extract the required information and then click on the next page, so you do not have to store things in lists that will loose context after navigating. Unfortunately your question is missing a few details, the url of the page could help here and make it clearer for everyone and also reproducible. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] thanks

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will review this article and update my question accordingly.